# STOP SLAVE with FORCE option

Tags: mysql

I am supposed to stop the slae immediately. I am trying to stop a slave. 
As there is a query running on the slave by SLAVE SQL thread, it is not stopping.
How to proceed now. its OK even if i lost this transaction. is there any option like FORCE STOP SLAVE...?

1) My approach is KILL the SQL thread

2) stop mysql

3) edit my.cnf with skip_slave_start

4) start mysql

5) CHANGE MASTER TO THE CORRECT POSTION

6) start slave.

Is there any better approach....???
Regards,
UDAY

Comment: Hi, Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91814/how-do-i-completely-disable-mysql-replication

Comment: Hi Sawant.. I couldnt able to stop the SLAVE. My main intension is either to do it with FORCE option if available or to KILL the query and to proceed further. matter in the link you atttached is not throwing light on any of these two...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above mentioned process works.